# Insert table from xls file to DataBase by input tyle="file"

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to upload my `xls` or `ods` file as a table into the database(I use `XAMPP`) by input type="file",
but I don't know if it can be done with the "CREATE TABLE filename.xls" command.
Is it possible? If not how to do it?

```html
<?php   
require_once "connect.php";
$connect =@new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
if($connect->connect_errno!=0) 
{
 
}
else //kod dziala.
{       
 echo "<br> We have connect! :)";
 $file= $_POST['wrzucenie']; // this is file name from input type="file".
 $query = "CREATE TABLE $file";
 if($rezult= @$connect->query($query))
 {
  echo "Table is create";
 }
 else
 {
  echo " <br>Table is not creat";
 }
 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

first create a table and all it attributes
then save your .xls file as .csv
then through phpmyadmin upload csv file to your table.

[this imaage show you how to upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBOEN.jpg)

Comment: __What__ makes you think that OP uses phpmyadmin?

Comment: I i know, but i don't want in this way. I want make a website, where i can insert table file from there.